# Why wont the mysql data values go in the options menu?

Tags: html, mysql

Im trying to do a drop down list of carpettypes for a website but every time i try and pull data from my mysql server it puts the carpet types in 3 separate select tags and i don't know why ? my code is pretty straightforward:

```
<?php
        include('config.inc');
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM DBForm");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo  "<select>";
          echo  "<option value=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['carpetTypes'] . "</option>";
          echo  "</select>";


        }

        echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

[image]

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd put the select outside of the while loop:

```
 echo  "<select>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo  "<option value=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['carpetTypes'] . "</option>";
     }
 echo  "</select>";
```

failure to do this will cause a single option select to be produced for every iteration

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `<select>` outside of the loop. Moreover, more compact solution can be

```
<?php
include 'connectDB.inc';
$options = "";
if($tablesQuery = mysqli_query($connect,"SHOW TABLES"))
    {   

        while($tables = mysqli_fetch_array($tablesQuery))
        {
            $options =  "$options"."<option>
            $tables[0]
            </option>";
        }
    }


?>
```

for getting the options from mysql. And keeping html simple :

```
<select id = "table1" name = "table1">
      <?php
        echo "Select table1 : <br> $options "; ?>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `"<select>"` to before the while loop and the `echo "</select>";` after the closing }

You only want to output the select tag once, the option tag for every item.